# When searching for a key in a dict why do I need to set the boolean condition to false

Tags: python, boolean

I am wondering why the code below requires us to put in found = false, and then found = true in the if statement.

```
def findinList():
  list = [["Dog" , "der Hund"] , ["Cat" , "die Katze"] , ["Bird" , "der Vogel"]]
  key = "Cat"
  found = false
  for item in list:
    if item[0] == key:
      print item[1]
      found = true
      break
  if not found:
    print "Value not in list"
```

This is my (mis)understanding. if item[0] == key (which it does) then the if statement is true. So shouldn't it just break out of it after it prints the item? Why do we require the found = false/true.

When you explain the answer can you please explain it in a very easy to understand definition as I am new to all this and too much detail will cause minor meltdowns in my understanding.

Comment: `False` and `True` should start with a capital letter. And naming your variable `list` will bite you when you want to use the builtin `list`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running the code without the found lines. You'll notice it has the following output:

```
die Katze
Value not in list
```

The found variable is used to make sure that the "Value not in list" string is only printed out if the value is not found. Otherwise, it would be printed out every time.

Answer (score 9):

You need the `found` flag because once a `for` loop ends, you can't really tell whether it stopped because you broke out of it or if the loop stopped on its own because it looped through the whole list.

Python actually has a neater way of doing this with an `else` block, which you may find a little easier to understand:

```
for item in list:
    if item[0] == key:
        print item[1]
        break
else:
    print "Value not in list"
```

The code in the `else` block will be executed only if you don't `break` out of the loop, which happens if you never find the word.

Also, what you have here isn't a dictionary. It's a list. You may want to use an actual dictionary:

```
words = {
    "dog": "der Hund",
    "cat": "die Katze",
    "bird": "der Vogel"
}
```

Your code will become much simpler:

```
key = 'dog'

if key in words:
    print words[key]
else:
    print "{} isn't in the dictionary".format(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
 if not found:
    print "Value not in list"
```

wouldn't work if you didn't set `found` to `True`, and it would run when it **was** found if you didn't set `found` to `False` (or some other false-y value) in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The code is attempting to find whether the word Cat is the first item of any of the sub-lists of the list 'list'. It does this by first setting found = false and then iterating until it finds one, then setting found = true.

In python, the boolean constants are True and False, not true and false, so I'm unsure if this will work. Also, there are some better approaches to solving this problem, such as:

```
catLists = [sub_list for sub_list in list if sub_list [0] == 'Cat']
```

This will return all the lists inside list that startwith Cat.